# wp_safe_redirect(); isn't redirecting, it just prints the given variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I think I'm either misinterpreting the [WP Codex's definition](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) of the `wp_safe_redirect()` function, or I'm being a womble and not using it correctly. (I didn't even know WP had a function like this, but hey learning every day right?)

So some scenario, I have a new instance of `WP_Query` that loops through a specific post type then pulls a single result based upon a ACF field meta_key. I simply want to redirect the user to the first and only found result.

**Here's my attempt;**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'locale' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'published' ),
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'meta_key'               => 'postal_town',
    'meta_value'             => $postal_town_result
);

$postcodeSearch = new WP_Query( $args );

if($postcodeSearch->have_posts()) : 
    while($postcodeSearch->have_posts()) : $postcodeSearch->the_post();

        $perma_url = the_permalink();
        wp_safe_redirect( $perma_url ); // just prints the url?
        exit; 

    endwhile; 
else:
    echo 'Oops, there are no posts.'
endif;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WordPress [the_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/):

> `the_permalink` Displays the permalink for the current post.

So that actually displays it, and after output the header redirect fails as headers have already been sent.

You want [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) that returns the permalink instead of displaying it:

```
    $perma_url = get_permalink();
    wp_safe_redirect( $perma_url );
    exit;
```

Also, with the following, or whatever WordPress's equivalent setting is would show you:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```